# Discovering and sharing controllers between aspnet mvc and webapi in aspnet core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a Spa client, which runs inside of a aspnet core web app (aspnet core spa template). The Api project is where the business logic and data access reside and can be called by other clients such as native, other Spas, etc… The web app is protected by a cookie middlewre with external providers to sign-in, while the web api is protected by bearer tokens.

[image]

We have noticed that if we add a reference in the Web app to the Api project, the Controllers defined in the Api project are available in the web app. So just by adding a reference, we can make a local ajax call to /api/data from Spa residing in the Web app. There is nothing extra we’re doing here, no custom controller resolvers, assembly loading, etc…

Is that how things now work in aspnet core mvc? Are we correct to assume that the web app will just discover the controllers, but ignore any program.cs/startup.cs from the Api project when it configures the host?

Answer (score 2):

No. This is not how it works. First, the delineation between "MVC" and "Web Api" is more pedantic than anything at this point. In Core, they are the same. If your project is only going to be an API, you can leave a few things out of the standard MVC services, but it still use "MVC". As a result, calling something an "API" or "MVC" project doesn't really mean anything. You can mix and match to whatever degree you need.

If you have two separate projects, then you should follow that and keep everything separate. One should not have a dependency on the other. You can always "call" your API from your MVC project, just as with any other HTTP-hosted service. However, you won't be able to take advantage of things like `UrlHelper` to generate URLs for your API action from your MVC project. You would just need to "know" these.

If you want the two projects to be tightly integrated, then they shouldn't be two projects. Just have one website project, and move all your API and MVC stuff into it. Then, you'll truly have everything shared.

Comment: Somehow the controllers are being discovered though, so putting aside whether architectually this makes sense, my question about how things work was more in terms of "when you add a reference like this, does it automatically discover and register these controllers"? The answer appears to be yes from what I am seeing. 
Also, I know you can always make an HTTP call, but this way, you don't have to do that. You can host the controllers inside the web for the purpose of SPA app calling it without any extra tokens. Api can be hosted in a different app for other clients.

Comment: Well, it's not "somehow". That's fairly standard. The routing framework scans assemblies to find controllers. However, it creates some oddities that may cause things to break. For example, it will be the StartUp.cs of the MVC project that runs, even though the controllers are from the API project. If those controllers depend on services defined in the API project, you application goes boom because they aren't registered by the MVC project. In general, it just makes it much harder to tell what's going on and tightly couples the two projects.

Comment: It would even be better to move the shared controllers into a class library, as at least then it's obvious that they don't benefit from any configuration other than what's provided by the project that references them (no StartUp.cs for example).